# Remix: IERC721 ownerOf() Function Infinite Gas Costs

Tags: solidity, remix, openzeppelin

i wanted to make a smart contract which checks if a specific address has a specific NFT. I already created the NFT and my Code in the Goerli Testnet. But when i want to run my function it gives me an Error, probably because in remix, next to my function, it says Infinite Gas Costs.

Here's the Error:

> call to NFTChecker.checkNFT errored: VM error: revert.
>
> revert
>
> The transaction has been reverted to the initial state. Note:
> The called function should be payable if you send value and the value
> you send should be less than your current balance. Debug the
> transaction to get more information.

Here's my Code:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.8;


import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/IERC721.sol";

contract NFTChecker {
    function checkNFT(address _wallet, address _nftContractAddress, uint256 _tokenId) public view returns (bool) {
        IERC721 nftContract = IERC721(_nftContractAddress);
        return (nftContract.ownerOf(_tokenId) == _wallet);
    }
}
```